# Texturize robot consisting of STL-files

Tags: gazebo, urdf, xacro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created robots links with CATIA exported them as STL an constructed my own robot with URDF. Now I'm able to move my little mobile robot around the world in Gazebo. Yeah.
Then I mounted an Universal Robot Arm on top of my rover and there where textures on the arm. I looked in the XACRO-Description and found out, they use DAE files with textures to colorize the robots links.
Is it possible (and if with which software) to import STL-files attach textures on it and export it as DAE as easy as possible?
How would you texturize my existing robot with STL files?

Thanks for your help
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297365/texturize-robot-consisting-of-stl-files/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many programs that can do this. Personally I'd use blender. It's free and very powerful will loads of you tube tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on 2018-07-27**:
Ok thanks. I did it. Worked fine for me.